# My Angular 9 app scrolling event has an issue where it does fire but the class name I am updating does not update the dom

Tags: angular, class, dynamic, scroll

I am using Angular material and when a scrolling I can fire an event. No problem. So now I am trying to change a class if a user scrolls by calling a method but for some reason the class name I set as a variable is not updated in the HTML. If I however fire the same method by using (click) event from any element the class name is updated correctly and the class changes in HTML. I know the method is called by scrolling and I know the class name is updates as I can see it in the console but for some reason it does not seem as if the class is updated perhaps in the dom when scrolling. I have no idea how to figure this out.

My HTML

```
 <div class="text">
                <span
                  style="text-align: left !important;"
                  [className]="classname"
                  >{{ dashboardname }}</span
                >
              </div>
```

My method

```
 scrollHandler() {
    // console.log(event);
    this.scrolling = true;
    this.classname = "responsivetextscroll";
    console.log(this.classname);
    console.log("you are scrolling");
  }
```

So this works

```
    <div (click)="scrollHandler()">
      TEST
    </div>
```

but scrolling does not although it definitely fires the method

Comment: 1) `[class.responsivetextscroll]="classname"`& `this.classname =true;` OR 2) `[ngClass]="classname "`. Just try one of these and see what happens.

Comment: unfortunately does not make difference. If I use click event still works however for number 2) So just to be clear, if I use click event the classname is updated not only on my console (where I track the classname) but also on the view. Text font get smaller. If I scroll the classname is still updated but the view is not. Still same font-size and if I do inspect it still old classname

Answer (score 0):

Check your `polyfills.ts`. I can only assume you have this uncommented:

```
(window as any).__zone_symbol__UNPATCHED_EVENTS = ['scroll'];
```

Which is not a bad idea, but you would have to manually trigger change detection on the scroll event:

```
constructor(private ngZone: NgZone) {}

scrollHandler() {
  this.ngZone.run(() => {
    this.scrolling = true;
    this.classname = "responsivetextscroll";
  });
}
```

Comment: Thanks Poul and you right it is commented out on my polyfill.ts. But your solution WORKS. Now I need to try and understand why. But really appreciate!!